# Install Light Table, worked for python then set it up for Julia now having problems with python

Tags: python, julia, lighttable

I installed Light Table and it seemed to work with my current set up Python.  However, once I set up Julia by modifying the `Settings: User behaviors` it no longer seems to work for me and give me the error.

`Looks like there was an issue trying to connect to the project. Here's what we got:
python: can't open file '"C:\Program Files\LightTable\plugins\python\py-src\ltmain.py"': [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

I have checked and the file `ltmain.py` does exist.

The only reason I think there might be a connection with Julia is because this is the only change in the setting that I made to light table.

```
Settings: User behaviors
 :app [(:lt.objs.style/set-skin "dark")

       (:lt.objs.langs.julia/julia-path "C:\\Program Files\\Julia 0.3.0-prerelease\\bin\\julia.exe")

       ]
```

I know there is likely not a connection with Julia, but any help that could be provided would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I had this problem immediately when downloading and using Light Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this issue in the Light Table issue tracker: https://github.com/LightTable/Python/issues/16

One solution recommended there:

1. Open C:\Program Files\LightTable\plugins\python\python_compiled.js
2. On line 96 replace `lt.plugins.python.escape_spaces.call(null,lt.plugins.python.py_path)` with `lt.plugins.python.py_path`
3. Save file and restart Light Table

<sub>Credit to GitHub user gpiancastelli for finding this solution.</sub>